# Update the text value in xml using select

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2016

I have an `AdhocQuery` table in which the `QUERYDEFNITION` column stores xml.

I have below XML. And I want to fetch and update this 8/14/2019 value to today's date. Please help me on how to do it.

I am using SQL Server 2016.

```
<f ObjectName="V_QUERY_PLEDGEINSTALLMENTS" ColumnName="BALANCE" ParentPath="V_QUERY_REVENUE\Pledge Installments" DisplayPath="V_QUERY_REVENUE\Pledge Installments" FilterOperator="IsGreaterThan" CompareType="And" UseLeftParenthesis="true" LeftParenthesisCount="1" IncludeCurrentNode="true" DataMartLastRefresh="0001-01-01T00:00:00">
  <Values>
    <v>0.01</v>
  </Values>
  <TranslatedValues>
    <v>0.01</v>
  </TranslatedValues>
  <DataType>Money</DataType>
</f>
<f ObjectName="V_QUERY_REVENUE" ColumnName="PLEDGESUBTYPE" ParentPath="V_QUERY_REVENUE" DisplayPath="V_QUERY_REVENUE" CompareType="And" UseRightParenthesis="true" RightParenthesisCount="1" IncludeCurrentNode="true" DataMartLastRefresh="0001-01-01T00:00:00">
  <Values>
    <v>UIF Telemkt Pledge</v>
  </Values>
  <TranslatedValues>
    <v>UIF Telemkt Pledge</v>
  </TranslatedValues>
  <DataType>String</DataType>
</f>
<f ObjectName="V_QUERY_PLEDGEINSTALLMENTS" ColumnName="DATE" ParentPath="V_QUERY_REVENUE\Pledge Installments" DisplayPath="V_QUERY_REVENUE\Pledge Installments" FilterOperator="IsBetween" CompareType="And" UseLeftParenthesis="true" UseRightParenthesis="true" LeftParenthesisCount="1" RightParenthesisCount="1" IncludeCurrentNode="true" DataMartLastRefresh="0001-01-01T00:00:00">
  <DateFilterTypes>
    <QueryDateFilterType>SpecificDate</QueryDateFilterType>
    <QueryDateFilterType>SpecificDate</QueryDateFilterType>
  </DateFilterTypes>
  <Values>
    <v>8/14/2019</v>
    <v>8/20/2019</v>
  </Values>
  <TranslatedValues>
    <v xsi:nil="true" />
    <v xsi:nil="true" />
  </TranslatedValues>
  <DataType>Date</DataType>
</f>
<f ObjectName="V_QUERY_REVENUE" ColumnName="SOURCECODE" ParentPath="V_QUERY_REVENUE" DisplayPath="V_QUERY_REVENUE" FilterOperator="DoesNotBeginWith" CompareType="And" UseLeftParenthesis="true" UseRightParenthesis="true" LeftParenthesisCount="1" RightParenthesisCount="1" IncludeCurrentNode="true" DataMartLastRefresh="0001-01-01T00:00:00">
  <Values>
    <v>5T</v>
  </Values>
  <TranslatedValues>
    <v>5T</v>
  </TranslatedValues>
  <DataType>String</DataType>
</f>

SELECT 
    QUERYDefiNitionXML.value('(/f[ColumnName/text()=("DATE")]/value/v/text())[1]', 'date') as PLEDGEDATE
FROM 
    Adhocquery
```

Answer (score 1):

I made your XML well-formed by adding a root element. Also, a mandatory namespace was missing. And the XPath expression was off.

> SQL

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, QUERYDEFNITION XML);
INSERT INTO @tbl (QUERYDEFNITION)
VALUES
(N'<root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <f ObjectName="V_QUERY_PLEDGEINSTALLMENTS" ColumnName="BALANCE"
       ParentPath="V_QUERY_REVENUE\Pledge Installments"
       DisplayPath="V_QUERY_REVENUE\Pledge Installments" FilterOperator="IsGreaterThan"
       CompareType="And" UseLeftParenthesis="true" LeftParenthesisCount="1"
       IncludeCurrentNode="true" DataMartLastRefresh="0001-01-01T00:00:00">
        <Values>
            <v>0.01</v>
        </Values>
        <TranslatedValues>
            <v>0.01</v>
        </TranslatedValues>
        <DataType>Money</DataType>
    </f>
    <f ObjectName="V_QUERY_REVENUE" ColumnName="PLEDGESUBTYPE" ParentPath="V_QUERY_REVENUE"
       DisplayPath="V_QUERY_REVENUE" CompareType="And" UseRightParenthesis="true"
       RightParenthesisCount="1" IncludeCurrentNode="true" DataMartLastRefresh="0001-01-01T00:00:00">
        <Values>
            <v>UIF Telemkt Pledge</v>
        </Values>
        <TranslatedValues>
            <v>UIF Telemkt Pledge</v>
        </TranslatedValues>
        <DataType>String</DataType>
    </f>
    <f ObjectName="V_QUERY_PLEDGEINSTALLMENTS" ColumnName="DATE"
       ParentPath="V_QUERY_REVENUE\Pledge Installments"
       DisplayPath="V_QUERY_REVENUE\Pledge Installments" FilterOperator="IsBetween"
       CompareType="And" UseLeftParenthesis="true" UseRightParenthesis="true"
       LeftParenthesisCount="1" RightParenthesisCount="1" IncludeCurrentNode="true"
       DataMartLastRefresh="0001-01-01T00:00:00">
        <DateFilterTypes>
            <QueryDateFilterType>SpecificDate</QueryDateFilterType>
            <QueryDateFilterType>SpecificDate</QueryDateFilterType>
        </DateFilterTypes>
        <Values>
            <v>8/14/2019</v>
            <v>8/20/2019</v>
        </Values>
        <TranslatedValues>
            <v xsi:nil="true"/>
            <v xsi:nil="true"/>
        </TranslatedValues>
        <DataType>Date</DataType>
    </f>
    <f ObjectName="V_QUERY_REVENUE" ColumnName="SOURCECODE" ParentPath="V_QUERY_REVENUE"
       DisplayPath="V_QUERY_REVENUE" FilterOperator="DoesNotBeginWith" CompareType="And"
       UseLeftParenthesis="true" UseRightParenthesis="true" LeftParenthesisCount="1"
       RightParenthesisCount="1" IncludeCurrentNode="true" DataMartLastRefresh="0001-01-01T00:00:00">
        <Values>
            <v>5T</v>
        </Values>
        <TranslatedValues>
            <v>5T</v>
        </TranslatedValues>
        <DataType>String</DataType>
    </f>
</root>');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

DECLARE @today DATE = GETDATE();

-- before
SELECT QUERYDEFNITION.value('(/root/f[upper-case(@ColumnName)="DATE"]/Values/v/text())[1]', 'DATE') as PLEDGEDATE
FROM @tbl;--    Adhocquery

UPDATE @tbl
SET QUERYDEFNITION.modify('replace value of (/root/f[upper-case(@ColumnName)="DATE"]/Values/v/text())[1]
               with (sql:variable("@today"))');
-- after
SELECT QUERYDEFNITION.value('(/root/f[upper-case(@ColumnName)="DATE"]/Values/v/text())[1]', 'DATE') as PLEDGEDATE
FROM @tbl;--    Adhocquery
```

Comment: Good answer, +1 from my side. I think, it is worth to point to the `@` in the XPath indicating an attribute's name...